# Сложное условие

Tags: php

Пишу словами: если переменная1 будет равна переменной2, а переменная3 будет пустая, а переменная4 будет содержать данные, тогда делай это...

Как то, что я написал, перевести на код PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$first = 1;
$second = 1;
$third = null;
$fourth = "abcd";
  if(($first === $second) && !(isset($third)) && !(empty($fourth))){
   echo "OK"; 
  } else {
    echo "error";
  }
?>
```

Как-то так, если я правильно понял вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(
    $p1 == $p2
    &&
    empty( $p3)
    &&
    !empty( $p4)
) {
    // ура ура
}
```

`&&` логическое **И**, `==` проверка равенства, [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) — проверка на пустое значение (есть свои ньюансы!), `!` логическое **НЕ**, `//` строчный комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

`if ($переменая1 == $переменая2 and $переменая3 == null and $переменая4 != null) { print ("action"); }`

Хотя, что такое "пустая переменная" - нужно ещё уточнять. Может быть Вам подойдет `isset`.